# Error al crear controlador

Tags: c#, controller

Tengo una API REST en c#, tiene un controlador y funciona bien pero, estoy tratando de crear un nuevo controlador con el generador de códigos y me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya recompilé el proyecto y sigue mostrando el mismo error.

Lo que quiero hacer es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Separar la lógica en 2 controladores para no tener un archio tan grande, pero al querer crear el archivo me marca ese error, empiezo a sospechar que tal vez sea porque sólo admite un archivo controlador.

Comment: Dos cosas: 

1- Puedes tener tantos controladores como tu aplicación necesite. 2- Los nombres de los controladores tienen un estándar. Controller deberá ser la última palabra en el nombre del archivo: No debe llamarse "UnidadesControllerResp", sino "UnidadesController". Aunque puedes modificar la forma en que son llamados los controladores, no es aconsejable alejarse del estándar. Puede que el error esté en la generación de plantillas

Comment: Ese lo generé a mano, sólo para la foto, el detalle es que cuando lo intento crear con el generador de código(lo nombro UnidadesController) me marca el error en la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error era porque se actualizaron algunos paquetes, entre ellos el de generacion de código, los degradé y todo funciona correctamente.